# Can I to use Library inside expressions on Azure Api Management?

Tags: c#, azure-api-management

I would like to use C# JUST Library for JSON to JSON transformation, similarly is used XSLT on API Manager, Could I to use this library?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, I suggest you to have your custom code hosted somewhere and call it using the Send-request policy to achieve the required processing you need on the data.

Otherwise, you need to build your custom logic using policy expression
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Comment: Thank you @Mohamad, policy expression is good option since I can use template liquid otherwise the logic isn't so trivial.

Comment: exactly, this is for your reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body